# Wordpress Integration with CRM(Property Listings)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, crm

I am developing a WordPress site for one Real Estate Company.
They want to integrate the new site to their existing CRM which contains real estate property listings.
They want all the listings on their new WordPress Site.
They sent me on XML feed for integration.

I have researched a lot about this topic but getting nowhere. 
Please guide me how to make this possible.

Comment: Please take a look on how to ask here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they provide feed, then you can use `php` to parse XML format. You can use php simpleXML to do that. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp) is a nice tutorial on that topic.

After that, populate the extracted data in your own custom style. (in case you don't need to save those data in database).